# "I don't smoke more cigarettes than i need to get a kick out of."

Tags: comparative-constructions

I heard someone say " **I don't smoke more cigarettes than i need to get a kick out of.**", and i was wondering whether what he said is grammatically correct.

Comment: That's...a good question. I can certainly parse it and determine what it *means*, but I'm not 100% sure it's grammatical.

Comment: I mean, it's definitely a valid construct to say "I don't [transitive verb] more [nouns] than I need to [verb]" (for example, "I don't breathe more air than I need to survive"). but "get a kick out of" as a verb phrase is tripping up my parser here.

Comment: What would your conclusive opinion about the sentence be?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is patently wrong, but I would say:

> I don't smoke more cigarettes than **necessary** to get a kick out of.

which would also avoid the repetitive "to to" in the proper form of your phrase "than (I need to) (to get)".

"a kick out of" sounds odd, but it may just be me. I would prefer "a kick *from*".

Comment: So, if he had used "I don't smoke more cigarettes than i need to to get a kick from." , would that be grammatically correct?

Answer (score -1):

From you original sentence

> I don't smoke more cigarettes than I need to get a kick out of.

the speaker is saying

> I don't smoke more cigarettes than I need to *(to)* get a kick out of *( it / them )*.

meaning

> I don't smoke more cigarettes than *necessary* to get a *nicotine* kick.

referring to the high one experiences during smoking.

The possible sloppiness may be due to the fact that it was spoken, possibly while having one of those cigarettes, possibly saying "to get a kick out of" while looking at the cigarette.